# GWT Flextable issue with only IE8 while removing the rows

Tags: gwt

In IE8, not able to remove all rows from the flextable in order to refresh the table with newer values.

The code works fine with other version of the browser like chrome and FF. But in IE8 it doesn't work.

Have tried all the methods still the row values remain the same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < someTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
            someTable.removeRow(0);
        }

        if (someTable.getRowCount() > 0) {
            someTable.removeAllRows();
        }

        someTable.clear(true);
        someTable.removeFromParent();
```

Comment: Is it possible you have ChromeFrame installed? I've seen issues (resolved from 2.5 - https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6665) where even with the ChromeFrame plugin disabled the GWT code mistakenly uses Chrome(WebKit)-specific handling instead of IE.

Comment: Issues seems to be only in IE8 browser. Tested the same in a separate machine with only IE8 installation. I even tried using JSNI method to empty the table rows but still on IE8 it doesn't work!